# how to fit view into cell android gridview

Tags: android, view, grid-layout

I am new to android and trying to make a calculator. I am using grid view to make UI for keypad as shown.[image: UI in the image]

how to make buttons occupy entire cell area where cell area auto adjusts with screen size. I know how to do it programatically but curious to know the xml way.I heard that we have to inflate linear layouts for each cell but cant figure out that linear layout parameters.

In short is there any way to give child width to the width of cell it is inside gridview.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this inside your cell

```
`<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1"/>`
```

gravity parameter sets position of text inside `TextView`

Comment: tried it but text view is occupying entire area allocated for grid layout not single cell